# Changing the quality of the transient process in a nonlinear system (in Mathematica)

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, adaptive-control

I urgently need advice and help.

I have a system of differential equations like this:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} == y[t] \cdot \alpha \cdot sin(\omega t) + \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha \cdot sin(\omega t))
   \\ \frac{dy}{dt} + h \cdot y(t) == \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-(x[t] - 2)^2}) \end{cases}$

Parameters: $\alpha = 0.3, h = 1, \omega = 2 \pi 0.5, x(0)=1/4, y(0)=0$

It corresponds to the following structural scheme:

[image]

The code that simulates such a system is shown below:
ClearAll["Global`*"]

```
pars = {\[Alpha]1 = 0.3, h1 = 1, \[Omega]1 = 2 Pi 0.5}

extr = Exp[-(x[t] - 2)^2]

sys = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    hpf1[t] \[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t] + 
     D[\[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t], t], 
   y'[t] + h1 y[t] == D[extr, t], x[0] == 1/4, y[0] == 0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 500}]
```

The numerical solution is presented below:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

**It can be seen that the transition process is a transition from the initial point to the final one with a certain character.**

**I need to change this character i.e. make the transition from one point to another *exponentially*.**
Like this:

[image]

What are the ways to solve this problem? What to do, add a regulator or manipulate the system of differential equations?

Please help me!

Comment: To be honest, I have some doubts that your system of differential equations models the structural diagram presented in the question. Especially this term $\alpha \, \sin(\omega t)\,y$ is very troublesome.

Comment: @Futurologist

I transferred the sum of the dither signal with the integrator to this integrator, and the coefficient D = 1. The second equation is the equation of the washout filter.

Answer (score 1):

The rate at which you converge is proportional to the gradient of your process, in your case $e^{-(x(t)-2)^2}$. However, for values of $x(t)$ far away from $2$ the gradient very quickly becomes tiny. For example if you use $x(0)=0$ the behaviour that you are trying to remove gets even more pronounced. In this case you could take the logarithm of the output of process before feeding it into the washout filter. However, this only works for processes for which you know that their outputs are always positive.

Comment: This decision does not suit me. In addition, we may not know the nonlinear mapping (as in this case). It is necessary to introduce something into the system (link or additional control signal), which provides a given transient process (in this case, exponential). Those. endow the system with adaptive properties. Try to look at it from a mathematical point of view. I'm not a mathematician, unfortunately.

Comment: @dtn without knowing the function or the location of its extremum it is impossible to ensure a desired transient.

Comment: Is this the final verdict? Even adaptive systems won't help?

Comment: @dtn may I ask why you want to try to enforce this convergence?

Comment: This is necessary for the standardization and unification of transients in such systems + the study of adaptive properties.

Comment: If you have sufficient mathematical qualifications, tell me how we can solve a similar problem from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: @dtn you could vary the amplitude of the dither signal, something like $$\alpha(t) = (\alpha_0 - \alpha_1)\,e^{-\beta\,t} + \alpha_1,$$ but I think that still wouldn't guarantee exponential convergence in general. It can be noted that your current convergence can already be bounded by exponential decaying functions, similar to how [this blue curve is bounded by this green exponential](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/AsymptoticStabilityImpulseScilab.png).

Comment: i don't need asymptotic exponential convergence. I need to transform the transient somehow.