# Changing the quality of the transient process in a nonlinear system (Part II)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, adaptive-control

My question is a continuation of the topic.

[Changing the quality of the transient process in a nonlinear system (in Mathematica)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910814/changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in-a-nonlinear-system-in-mathemat)

Unfortunately, last time I didn’t get any help, so I decided to reformulate the question.

I have a system of differential equations like this:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = y \cdot \alpha \cdot sin(\omega t) + \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha \cdot sin(\omega t))
   \\ \frac{dy}{dt} + y = \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)) \end{cases}$

where:
$f(t)$ - Any function that has one extreme (minimum or maximum). For example $f(t) = e^{-(x - x_{*})^2}$

$x$ and $y$ - variables of the system of differential equations.

$x_{*}$ - the point at which the maximum or minimum of the function $f(t)$ is reached.

Let's pay special attention to the variable $x$.

Parameters: $\alpha = 0.3, \omega = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 0.5, x(0)=1/4, y(0)=0$

The solution is to go from the starting point $x(0)$ to the point $x_{*}$ at which the minimum or maximum of the function $f(t)$ is reached.

For my system with such parameters, the solution will look like this:

[image]

It can be seen that the transition process is a transition from the initial point to the final one with a certain character, which is added to the additional sinusoidal signal $\alpha \cdot sin(\omega t)$.

It is necessary to change the nature of the transition from one point to another, making it exponential (naturally retaining an additional sinusoidal signal $\alpha \cdot sin(\omega t)$), i.e. it must be described by law:

$x(t)=(x(0)−x_{*}) \cdot exp(-t) + x_{*} + \alpha \cdot sin(\omega t)$,

Like this:

[image]

The problem is complicated by the fact that the function $f(t)$ and the point at which its minimum/maximum $x_{*}$ is located, generally speaking, are not known to us.

*How to get out of the situation using the structure of the differential equation? Add additional input signal? Include an additional differential equation in the system? Use adaptive techniques?*

Help! Please give at least some idea. I am desperate and my hands give up.

Comment: It looks like a control problem but in control issues, the formulation is on the form $$\dot x = f(x,u)$$ in which $x$ is the state and $u$ the control. In your formulation is not clear to me what is $u$ and what is $x$. Could you explain what are yours $u,x$ ?

Comment: How much exactly do you know about $f(t)$ i.e. if you want to do some feedback control can you for example set $u=-f(t)$, if not do you know any bounds on $f(t)$?

Comment: @abc1455

 I am answering your question.

The structure of $f (t)$ is not known to us, but this signal is available for measurement. $f(t)$ - black-box.

Comment: The block diagram of the control system is as follows. 

[https://ibb.co/fDxJqBD](https://ibb.co/fDxJqBD)

Block G - estimation of the gradient of the function, i.e. $\frac{df}{dt}$.

Comment: i.e. $\frac{df}{dx}$, excuse me

Comment: Is this [link](https://ibb.co/fDxJqBD) the system that you want to control? $\dot{x}=u+\frac{df}{dx}$

Comment: @abc1455

This is the control system. She looks for such a value of $x$ at which the extremum of the function $f(t)$ is reached. I need to make sure that the transition from the starting point $x(0)$ to the maximum / minimum point $x_{*}$ in such a system always follows a given exponential law with a given time constant.

Comment: so what you are trying to do is to make $x$ converge to $x^*$ exponentially and you don't know $x^*$

Comment: @abc1455, yes...

Comment: Does the output of your system need to be $x$?

Comment: @abc1455, yes...

Comment: could you put your original system in the state space form $\dot{x}=g(x,u,t)$ and $y=h(x,u)$ and specify whether it is autonomous or not i.e. does $f$ depend on $x$ or depend $t$ explicitly

Comment: @abc1455:

Affine state space, is that what you need? If yes, then I have transformed this equation using Mathematica:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235544/67019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly adaptive control won't help either, your problem is not in the stability of the system but its performance.

Assuming that $f$ has a minimum then you could let your system be
$$
\dot{y}=-\alpha \frac{df}{dy}\\
\dot{x}+\beta x =\beta y+\gamma (\omega \cos{\omega t}+\beta\sin{\omega t})
$$

if $\alpha >> \beta$ then the response would be exponential provided that $f$ is of function of $y$, if $f$ is a function of $t$ explicitly then let $T$ be the time it takes to reach its critical point then if $\beta << \alpha <<\frac{1}{T}$ it will work. The idea behind this is to make $y$ converge to the maximum or minimum much faster than $x$.

If $f$ is dependent on $x$ then you could make $\dot{x}=\beta u'+\gamma \sin \omega t$ where $u'=sign(-\frac{df}{dx})$ for $\frac{df}{dx} \neq0$ and $u'=0$ when $\frac{df}{dx}=0$. This system will converge to $x^*$ in a linear manner when  $\gamma >> \beta$

If $f$ has a maximum then
$$
\dot{y}=\alpha \frac{df}{dy}\\
\dot{x}+\beta x =\beta y+\gamma (\omega \cos{\omega t}+\beta\sin{\omega t})
$$
or
$\dot{x}=\beta u'+\gamma \sin \omega t$ where $ u'=sign(\frac{df}{dx})$ for $\frac{df}{dx} \neq0$ and $u'=0$ when $\frac{df}{dx}=0$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116880/discussion-on-answer-by-abc1455-changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in).