# Extension of an ODE to dynamical system with certain properties

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

We have a gradient ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$

where $f=-x^2$

I want the condition to be met on a given system:

$x''+x'=0$

I.e. initial ODE turns into a dynamic system:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx} \\ x''+x'=0 \end{cases}$

But, in order to solve such a system, an auxiliary variable is needed (for example, $y$).

What are the ways to introduce it into this dynamic system?

**Remark:**
I did it like this. I added an auxiliary variable $u$ and got this system of equations:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx} + u + u' \\ x''+x'=0 \end{cases}$

Then he numerically solved such a system.

Here the problem is such that *for a numerical solution it is required to know the value of the first derivative of the variable $x$, i.e. $x'(0)=?$*, *but we assume that it is unknown and cannot be obtained in any way.*

*Moreover, it is required to know it exactly, because otherwise the system stops converging to the maximum / minimum point.*

**!I don’t know how to overcome this problem!**

Comment: $x'+2x=0$ has a solution set. $x''+x'=0$ has a solution set. These two sets only have the zero function in common. What does "I want the condition to be met" mean in more detail?

Comment: @LutzLehmann
For the solution of this gradient equation to satisfy the specified condition. Please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923222/changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in-a-nonlinear-system-part-ii

Comment: Is $\frac{dx}{dt}=x'$? If so, isn't your system equivalent to the planar system $(u'=v, v'=-\nabla f)$ under the change of coordinates $u=x,\, v=x'$?

Comment: @PepeToro And...?

Comment: what do you mean and?
Given that you know what $f$ is, then you can solve, at least numerically, the problem no? If you do not know or do not want to fix $x'(0)$, then you could set it as a parameter $x'(0)=\alpha$ and express solutions in terms of $\alpha$. With $f=-x^2$, the systems would become $u'=v,\, v'=2x$, which seems solvable.

Comment: @PepeToro
There are no problems to solve numerically. I mean the function $f$ is unknown. If we cannot correctly determine $x'(0)$, then the system incorrectly converges to the extremum point Form your comment as a answer.

Comment: @PepeToro
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959136/changing-the-quality-of-the-transient-process-in-a-nonlinear-system-part-iii This is what I am trying to achieve.